# Variable one less than another variable

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript is there a way to write an if statement that is true if variable B is only 1 less than variable A?  I know that I could do if(B < A), but I need to check if A is only 1 less than B

Comment: You say _"B is only 1 less than variable A"_ but later say _"A is only 1 less than B"_ ... so which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally, "variable B is only 1 less than variable A" is

```
if (a - b === 1) { }
```

But if You really hate strict equality, You can go with

```
if (!(a - b - 1)) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add 1 to b and then compare to a:

```
if(b+1 === a)
```

or subtract 1 from a 
             (as @TravisJ pointed out, this is the preferred method  as it prevents the 1 being appended in case of a string) :

```
if(a-1 === b)
```

Comment: The subtraction is preferable in order to avoid accidentally appending a string using +.

Comment: Does this change the value of the variable outside the condition as well?

Comment: @suprkain no it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
if(a== b-1)
```